# zip lib (zlib, bzip2) and mono support

Tags: c#, .net, mono, zip, bzip2

Can you advise me zip lib witch support zib and bzip2 algorithm

My requirements:

1. Fully .net managed code
2. Free
3. Popular
4. Can be used with mono

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [SharpZipLib](http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Default.aspx).

From the [FAQ](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib_FAQ.ashx):

> **What formats does SharpZipLib support?**
>
> Sharpzip supports Zip files using both stored and deflate compression methods and also supports old (PKZIP 2.0) style and AES encryption, tar with GNU long filename extensions, gzip, zlib and raw deflate, as well as BZip2.
>
> Zip64 is supported while Deflate64 is not yet supported. AES is supported for encryption and decryption except for the ZipInputStream class (use ZipFile with an input stream until this is completed).
>
> **Can I use SharpZipLib in my commercial application?**
>
> Yes you can, there is an exception in the licensing terms that allows linking #Zip with any application. The source code to #Zip is however still GPLed and so any changes to the source code you make must be made available to everyone.

Comment: Just be aware that the version of SharpZipLib shipped with Mono is old, outdated, and has known bugs. Bundling the current version with you application works fine though.

Comment: Thanks all for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I've created [SharpCompress](http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/) to be a consistent API for many format types (bzip2, gzip, zip, rar, etc.) and is completely free (MS-PL).  Let me know any needs/changes/suggestions.

Comment: @Thanks a lot, but is SharpCompress have zlib format support?

Comment: it supports Deflate which is used by zip and gzip.  As far as I'm aware, zlib is an implementation of Deflate.